# Backbone - why doesn't this helper function work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a helper module in my backbone app that includes a toggleVisibility function:

```
return{
    toggleVisibility: function( ele ){  
        if ( ele.hasClass('hidden') ){          
            ele.removeClass('hidden').show(200);
        } else {            
            ele.addClass('hidden').hide(200);
        }
    },
};
```

Now, if I call this in my view:

```
Helpers.toggleVisibility( this.$el );
```

It doesn't work. However, if I do the following instead of the call, i get the desired functionality, the exact same as what I'm doing in the function:

```
this.$el.removeClass( 'hidden').show(200);
```

Further to this, the Helper function works for other elements that aren't in the view. Any pointers as to what's going here? Pretty new to backbone, so assume newbie explanation please :)

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that the element doesn't actually have the `hidden` class. The check for that is the only difference between your two versions.

Comment: Probably you do not need this helper? http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/

Comment: I'm starting to think that I don't. Maybe I'm getting carried away with trying to modularise ( a word? ) everything. Thanks for the replies, I think I'll put this down to an exercise in keeping things simple...

Comment: Are you calling your helper before, after or during the view's render? Try calling it after you have added the view's `$el` to the page.